# AngularJS only works once per page after updating version from 1.0.8 to 1.2

Tags: angularjs

After updating version of angular in my project (1.0.8 to 1.2), it stopped working fine. I have installed angularjs, jquery and foundation.

I have this view (haml), which behaves OK (shows the games) only first time, or when I press ctrl+F5:

```
#myDivGrid{'ng-show' => "layout == 'grid'", 'ng-cloak' => ''}
   = div_for(game)

#myDivList{'ng-show' => "layout == 'list'", 'ng-cloak' => ''}
   = div_for(game)
```

And this condition in my controller:

```
$scope.layout = 'grid'

if $window.innerWidth < 658
  $scope.layout = 'list'
```

If I go again to this page through the menu, it does not shows anything (no error in console).

I've tried to delete the 'ng-cloak' option in both divs. It shows OK again the first time but when I go again through the menu to that page, both divs are shown.

I've also tried having only the first div, no ng-show nor ng-cloak options and it displays fine every time I go to the page, but if I write the ng-cloak the div is only shown if I press ctrl+F5.

I have the same issue with ng-repeat elements, but that's another topic.

When I had Angular v.1.0.8 installed everything worked fine.

Thanks!

Comment: The entire project (development stage) is uploaded in github: https://github.com/yagoff/mooffin/tree/dev_branch